# Formatting all date properties in C# object list

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, datetime-format

I'm having huge issues with formatting the DateTime of each date property within a list of objects. Here's a few examples of what I've tried so far:

```
var data = vulnerabilityList.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList()
    .Select(v => { v.PublishedDate = 
    v.PublishedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); return v; });
```

and

```
var data = vulnerabilityList.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize).ToList()
    .Select(v => { v.PublishedDate = 
        DateTime.ParseExact(v.PublishedDate.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", 
            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture); return v; });
```

Ultimately I want the format as 31/12/2017 and it'll be returned as JSON so it seems the data annotations on the vulnerability class are ignored. The first example doesn't compile as obviously it's trying to set a DateTime as a string, but I included it as an example of what I'm looking to do.

Thanks

Comment: The question is : do you want a fixed format date time ? (meaning, not dependant on culture of the client) ? If true, maybe you should consider to model the date as a string on the client side. Use some Data Transfer Object which has a string type for your date field.

Comment: @Pac0 Thanks, that's the approach I have just taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A datetime is a representation of a date and time using a number, and it doesn't have an inherent format. It's intended for you to format it how you want it when you read it or display it to users. So doing something like this:

```
v.PublishedDate = (DateTime)v.PublishedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Is only going to set the publish date to dd/MM/yy 00:00:00 (if it did work).

I believe what you'll need to do is either change how you're parsing your JSON in the end, or store the DateTime as a string in a new property for reading.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I'll look at formatting the output in the resulting JSON.